# How can I install a Python package using local archive?

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-packaging, connect-timeout

I'm not being able to install packages as lxml, BeautifulSoup4, etc. from Local archives.
I'm using a venv and directly from the cmd.

I tried to install packages with the following lines:`py -m pip install lxml`& `py -m pip install ./downloads/lxml-5.1.0.tar.gz` with the file previously downloaded.

```
Processing c:\users\t985syc\downloads\lxml-5.1.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024A3AC39EE0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cython/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024A3A55C6B0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cython/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024A3AD5FFE0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cython/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024A3AD5EF60>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cython/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024A3AD5F1A0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cython/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython>=3.0.7 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython>=3.0.7
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Try something like: py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/dir/ lxml   (where local/dir is the path to where you have your download)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but I received the same error message.

Comment: One of the requirements of the package you're trying to install requires a certain version of Cython (>=3.0.7), and pip is unable to access the internet and hence cannot download the dependency. Either enable an internet connection, or install cython from a local archive